# Time-reversal symmetry for spinful fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, many-body, second-quantization

For a continuum model of non-interacting spinful fermions with many-body Hamiltonian

$\hat{\mathcal{H}}=\int_{\mathbb{R_2}}d\vec{k}\begin{pmatrix} \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}\uparrow} & \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}\downarrow} \end{pmatrix}H(\vec{k})\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\hat{c}_{\vec{k}\uparrow}\\
\hat{c}_{\vec{k}\downarrow}\\
\end{array}
\right)$,

time-reversal symmetry acts as $T=i\sigma_{y}K$ on the single particle Bloch Hamiltonian $H(\vec{k})$, with $\sigma_{y}$ and $K$ denoting the second Pauli matrix and complex conjugation, respectively. How can I show $T$ actually acts like this from demanding that $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ commutes with the time-reversal operator $\mathcal{T}$ acting on the many-body Fock space, $[\mathcal{H},\mathcal{T}]=0$ ?